# Eclipse: The .classpath containsa a library that will not be available during continuous integration

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bndtools

I get this error even though the jar file, osgi.core-4.0.1.jar is there in my local .bnd folder.

```
Eclipse: The .classpath containsa a library that will not be available during continuous integration: C:/Users/UserName/.bnd/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fbndtools%2Fbundle-hub%2Fmaster%2Fosgi.core/osgi.core-4.0.1.jar
```

The error is on line 1 (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`), of the .classpath in my project's main API (com.mycompany.test.api)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin_test" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="aQute.bnd.classpath.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/UserName/.bnd/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fbndtools%2Fbundle-hub%2Fmaster%2Fosgi.core/osgi.core-4.0.1.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/UserName/.bnd/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fbndtools%2Fbundle-hub%2Fmaster%2Fosgi.core/osgi.core-4.0.1.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="bsn" value="osgi.core"/>
            <attribute name="type" value="REPO"/>
            <attribute name="project" value="org.example.impls"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

What could be the problem? Thank you all in a advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using Bndtools, you do not edit the `.classpath` file to add jars to compile path. Instead edit the `bnd.bnd` file and add the jar to the `-buildpath`. Bndtools will then have Bnd read the `bnd.bnd` file and use the `-buildpath` and `-testpath` information to populate the `aQute.bnd.classpath.container` classpath container.